# Merge three lists with linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have three classes -

```
public class Type
{
   public int TypeId {get;set;}
   public string TypeName {get;set;}
}

public class SubType
{
   public int SubTypeId {get;set;}
   public string SubTypeName {get;set;}
}

public class Association
{
   public int TypeId {get;set;}
   public int SubTypeId {get;set;}
}
```

The `Association` gives the mapping between `Type` and `SubType`.

I have lists of each class - `List<Type>`, `List<SubType>`, `List<Association>`.

I want to merge them all into another like this - `List<TypeInfo>.` 
The `TypeId` and `SubTypeId` coming from the `Assoication`, the `TypeName` coming from `Type` and the `SubTypeName` coming from `SubType`.

```
public class TypeInfo 
{
   public int TypeId {get;set;}
   public string TypeName {get;set;}
   public int SubTypeId {get;set;}
   public string SubTypeName {get;set;}
}
```

Is there an easy way with `linq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very straight forward:

```
List<Type> types = ...
List<SubType> subTypes = ...
List<Association> associations = ...

IEnumerable<TypeInfo> query =
    from type in types
    join association in associations on type.TypeId equals association.TypeId
    join subType in subTypes on association.SubTypeId equals subType.SubTypeId
    select new TypeInfo()
    {
        TypeId = association.TypeId,
        SubTypeId = association.SubTypeId,
        TypeName = type.TypeName,
        SubTypeName = subType.SubTypeName,
    };

List<TypeInfo> typeInfos = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming types and subTypes are of type List and List respectively.

```
var associations = new List<Association>();
var typeInfoes = associations
                .Join(types, a => a.TypeId, t => t.TypeId,
                        (a, t) => new TypeInfo
                        {
                            TypeId = a.TypeId,
                            TypeName = t.TypeName,
                            SubTypeId = a.SubTypeId,
                            SubTypeName = ""
                        }
                )
                .Join(subTypes, ti => ti.SubTypeId, st => st.SubTypeId, 
                        (ti, st) => new TypeInfo
                        {
                            TypeId = ti.TypeId,
                            TypeName = ti.TypeName,
                            SubTypeId = ti.SubTypeId,
                            SubTypeName = st.SubTypeName
                        }
                )
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Enigmativity answer is better as it uses join. Edited to use expression chain syntax as an alternative to query syntax for the join.